# Unsubscribe Behavior Subject

Tags: angular

Like in the header i need to unscubscribe the behavior subject in my component. The behavior subject is in Global static service. Heres the behavior subject in

```
private _salesPlanId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(undefined);
salesPlanId$ = this._salesPlanId.asObservable();
changeSalesPlanId(data) {
    this._salesPlanId.next(data);
}
```

And i start subscribe it inside my component in lifececyle OnInit :

```
ngOnInit() {

   this.mySubscription = this.service.salesPlanId$.subscribe(id => {
        if (id === undefinied){
           this.service.getId.subscribe(id => {
                 this.service.changeSalesPlanId.next(id);
           }
         }else{
               this.id = id;
              }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that i want to on destroy component to unsubscribe element and 
chang this behavior subject again to undefinied and i do this like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.flex.changeSalesPlanId(undefined);
}
```

But on OnDestroy after usubscribe i change a salesPlan Inside service and i see this component recive undefinied value  and start geting id again? Any walkaroun ?

Comment: You create a new subscription to getId in ngOnInit every time an undefined id is emitted by salesPlanId$. But you never unsubscribe from these new subscriptions. You probably want to use the switchMap operator, and thus have a single subscription.